# Organic 2d tree generation

Tags: procedural-generation

I'm looking for a code to generate organic 2d trees like thiskind of shapes

[image: Organic tree 01]

[image: Organic tree 02]

Gerard Ferrandez has an example to generate some tree but not organic like the picture shape https://codepen.io/ge1doot/pen/BGWzgW?editors=0010

Any recomendation will be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It could be generated as a Lindenmayer System (L-system) with some rules for branch widths (plus some fractal noise) and branch bifurcation. They are parameters you can play with.

You can find lots of resources in the [website](http://algorithmicbotany.org) of the Biological Modeling and Visualization research group in the Department of Computer Science at the University of Calgary. Professor Przemyslaw Prusinkiewicz is the researcher who popularized these systems, and he has made his [main book](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop.pdf) *The algorithmic beauty of plants* available for free.

Comment: And you can try it for free interactively with the free Houdini appentice version.

Comment: Can I mix this with voronoi patterns?